# How to SUMIF if value matches reference?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet that looks like this, for budget keeping.

I want people to be able to put lines into the "expenditures" section on the right, and include one of the budget codes (blue highlight). For example, if someone spent $30 on "House Bugdet", they would put 30 in the amount column (yellow) and "HB" in the Budget code column (blue).

My idea is that I can use these budget codes to calculate how much of each budget has been spent in the red-highlighted column. e.g. HB should show that $30 has been spent, and HA should show that $20 has been spent, in the example below.

[image: The spreadsheet]

Here is the spent column (red) formula I've been working on for a while, but I feel like I don't fully understand `SUMIF()`.

```
=SUMIF(H:H,B3=REFERENCE(NULL,ROW(),H,NULL),K:K)
```

I'm pretty inexperienced at spreadsheet formulae so any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was very simple and required careful reading of the docs.

The criterion can be a cell reference that it compares the range to, so:

```
=SUMIF(H:H,B3,K:K)
```

worked for me! (Where B3 changes depending on the row: C3, D3, etc.)